# samsung phone inputmethodservice onScreenStateChanged crash

Tags: android, android-edittext, samsung-mobile, android-input-method, android-viewgroup

Unable to detect the cause of crash, this crash only occur on samsung devices

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at android.inputmethodservice.ExtractEditText.onScreenStateChanged (ExtractEditText.java:246)
  at android.view.View.dispatchScreenStateChanged (View.java:16285)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchScreenStateChanged (ViewGroup.java:3177)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchScreenStateChanged (ViewGroup.java:3177)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchScreenStateChanged (ViewGroup.java:3177)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchScreenStateChanged (ViewGroup.java:3177)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchScreenStateChanged (ViewGroup.java:3177)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchScreenStateChanged (ViewGroup.java:3177)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchScreenStateChanged (ViewGroup.java:3177)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchScreenStateChanged (ViewGroup.java:3177)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$1.onDisplayChanged (ViewRootImpl.java:1273)
  at android.hardware.display.DisplayManagerGlobal$DisplayListenerDelegate.handleMessage (DisplayManagerGlobal.java:939)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6776)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Can anyone please help me to point out the reason of this crash. Never face this crash while testing, only get report from play store console